# How to connect from Linux to Oracle database

Tags: ubuntu, database

What do I need to install on my Ubuntu Linux to connect to remote Oracle Database Server using my username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SQL client.

I recommend Oracle SQL Developer:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

With this client you can connect to many RDBMS including Oracle.

Comment: do i need sql client even if I want to connect from java

Comment: Java SDK should come out of the box with a bunch of drivers that allow you to connect to Oracle and various dbs. Checkout JDBC API.